# How to pad a CSV first column with zeroes in awk?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, gawk

I have a CSV like this:

```
1,"Paris","3.57"
10,"Singapore","3.57"
211,"Sydney","3.28"
324,"Toronto Center","3.33"
```

I'd like to pad the first column with zeroes to get:

```
001,"Paris","3.57"
010,"Singapore","3.57"
211,"Sydney","3.28"
324,"Toronto Center","3.33"
```

I tried to assign the first column to the output of `printf` with awk:

```
awk '{ $1 = printf("%03d", $1); print }' my.csv
```

But it gives me a syntax error :

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { $1 = printf("%03d", $1); print }
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
```

It doesn't work either if I quote the printf function.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want just to format the text of one field then you can use `sprintf` of `awk`.

```
   awk '{ $1=sprintf("%03d", $1)}1' csvfile
```

Or standard way:

```
   awk '{printf "%03d %s\n", $1,$2}' csvfile
```

As per update by OP in question:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{ $1=sprintf("%03d", $1)}1' csvfile
```

Comment: I updated my question with correct field separator and text delimiters.

Answer (score 5):

`printf` is not a function, it is a keyword, and its result cannot be assigned.

To return a formatted string, use `sprintf` (which *is* a function):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ $1 = sprintf("%03d", $1) } 1' file
```

It is necessary to set `FS` (via `-F`) and `OFS` so that when awk reformats the line, the field separators remain intact.

As pointed out in the comments, using `%d` can potentially lead to problems when the input starts with a `0`, as numbers with a leading `0` are interpreted as octal. This can break on input like `08` because 8 is outside of the octal range (0-7).

One way to get around this is to use `%03.0f`, which interprets the input as a floating point value, with the output precision set to `0`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ $1 = sprintf("%03f.0", $1) } 1' file
```

(the second `0` in the format specifier can in fact be omitted)

Comment: this is the solution I've used in my script, be careful when printing out numbers with leading zeroes, they may be treated like octal numbers, better to use "f" instead of "d" in formatting string - in this example:
`awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ $1 = sprintf("%03.f", $1) } 1' file`

Comment: @RLapinski good point, I updated the answer to mention that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf("%03d", $1) ; print " "$2}' my.csv
```